# How to add an integer to a constant in Java ASM bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to add an `integer` variable `x` to a static `int` variable named `count` using java ASM.

After a lot of searching, I found a way to add a fixed integer to a static int variable

```
                InsnList numCounting = new InsnList();

                // insert count++
                numCounting.add(new FieldInsnNode(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, classNode_c.name, "count", "I"));
                numCounting.add(new InsnNode(Opcodes.ICONST_1));
                numCounting.add(new InsnNode(Opcodes.IADD));
                numCounting.add(new FieldInsnNode(Opcodes.PUTSTATIC, classNode_c.name, "count", "I"));    
                mn.instructions.insert(node, numCounting);
```

How do I generalize this such that I can add an arbitrary `int` to `count`?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really test this code right now, but this should work

```
            InsnList numCounting = new InsnList();

            // insert count++
            numCounting.add(new FieldInsnNode(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, classNode_c.name, "count", "I"));
            numCounting.add(new LdcInsnNode( x )); // Load a constant onto the stack, asm will put that constant in the constant pool for you
            numCounting.add(new InsnNode(Opcodes.IADD));
            numCounting.add(new FieldInsnNode(Opcodes.PUTSTATIC, classNode_c.name, "count", "I"));    
            mn.instructions.insert(node, numCounting);
```

(My usual approach with asm is to write the method i want to generate with asm in pure java, compile it and look at the resulting bytecode with javap. Thats usually a good indication what opcodes to use.)